# Why does powerNumber() add a new number to the vector when I am inside the function but the number disappears once the function is executed?

Tags: c++

Solution is probably pretty easy but I can't figure it out. How do I make a permanent change to the vector and not only a change that takes effect inside the function? I debugged it and I can see that "numbers" is updated with the value I want it to have but it disappears as soon as it is executed.

```
using namespace std;
bool checkVal();
vector<int> getNumbers();
void setPowerball(vector<int> numbers);

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    vector<int> numbers = getNumbers();
    setPowerball(numbers);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << numbers[i];
        cout << " ";
    }
}

bool checkVal(vector<int> numbers, int size, int value)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if (numbers[i] == value)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void setPowerball(vector<int> numbers)
{
    for (int i = 4; i < 5; i++)
    {
        int last = rand() % 26 + 1;
        if (checkVal(numbers, i, last))
        {
            i--;
        }
        else
        {
            numbers.push_back(last);
        }
    }
}

vector<int> getNumbers()
{
    vector<int> numbers;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        int num = rand() % 69 + 1;
        if (checkVal(numbers, i, num))
        {
            i--;
        }
        else
        {
            numbers.push_back(num);
        }
    }

    sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());
    return numbers;
}
```

Comment: Because you're passing a _copy_ of the `numbers` vector, so the changes are made only to that copy. Make the functions take a reference instead.

Comment: Contrary to your subject line, there is no function named `powerNumber()` in your code.   In any event, if a function modifies an argument that has been passed to it by value, the caller has no visibility of the changes.   Passing by value means that a *copy* of the object supplied by the caller is passed, so the function modifies the copy without touching the original, and that copy ceases to exist when the function returns.  All of your functions have their argument passed by value.

Comment: @Tanishq-Banyal   Point is that, if the OP can't get the specifics of their question, they can't expect a good answer.   In software (development, code, etc) the cause of most problems is in small details, and getting small details wrong in a question substantially increases chance that the question misleads people who try to help and reduces chances of getting useful/relevant answers.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing arguments to `setPowerBall` function by value. So whenever it's called, it gets its private **copy** of the vector, which [gets destructed at the end of function scope.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2321511/14976549)

Instead you should be passing the arguments by reference in this case.

```cpp
void setPowerball(vector<int>& numbers)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

##### MAIN POINTS :-

1. Notice the **&** in function declaration. It implies taking a [lvalue reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33829606/difference-between-rvalue-reference-and-lvalue-reference-as-argument).
2. References allow you to modify the original variable without making a **copy**.
3. References are also cheaper to pass in case of objects like std::string or std::vector. But for primitive types like int or float, pass by value is faster.

***Note :*** You could also have used pointers to do the same but using References is recommended and safer way. Rule of the thumb is *Use references when you can, and pointers when you must*